# Facebook API: Including an image in the wall post

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

According to the [Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) all I have to do is add a "picture" property to the post object... But this is not working, here's my code:

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "publish_stream,offline_access")]
    public ActionResult Share(string message, string link, string picture, string name)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
        var postArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        postArgs["message"] = message;
        postArgs["link"] = link;
        postArgs["picture"] = picture;
        postArgs["name"] = name;

        fb.Post("/me/feed", postArgs);
        return Json(new {result = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What value are you sending for picture? It needs to be a full url, eg http://www.example.com/photo.jpg.  Also, it needs to be a URL that Facebook servers can access because Facebook will cache the image and then turn your link into their cached image url.

Comment: @bkaid: It returned a json object: `{"id":"1279802614_2095710473911"}`, shouldn't that mean everything went okey?

Comment: Yeah - what does the facebook post look like on the users wall?

Comment: @bkaid: Well the post includes all the passed data except the picture. So it is basically a normal wall post (text only) with a link that points to the item, but no picture...

Comment: could it be because I'm posting from my local machine?! I did not think of that but I think this could be it... will give it a try!

Comment: Updated the answer - if Facebook can't access the image then it wont render it because they cache those images.  Post the image url you are using and I can try to access it for you.